# how to handle Shopify Checkout

Tags: flutter, shopify

I'm writing my own app to interact with my Shopify store using **Flutter**.

My app at this point is very simple, I'm only trying to complete a payment. I'm using basically only 2 packages **shopify_flutter** and **Pay** (to handle payments with ApplePay).

Using the real device to test the payment method I had no errors but after a call to **checkoutCompleteWithTokenizedPaymentV3** it returned an ID (apparently a success).
When I checked my store I found it the order was not completed, the cart was an abandoned cart. (in other words the payment wasn't completed)

Do I need to do something else after the process **checkoutCompleteWithTokenizedPaymentV3**?

Comment: Define, the payment wasn't completed. Was there even a trace of an order in your store? If there was, that is one thing. If there was no order, that is another. You said you got an ID, so that means, there should be one. If there is, what is the payment status? Unpaid? Wow. So complete the payment. Anyway, more details from you would help.